# Is the following screenshot code acceptable for use in an App Store app?

Tags: ios, screenshot

I am using this code to take a screenshot in my app on iOS 5.0 app:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(viewImage, nil, nil, nil);
```

Is this an acceptable way of taking a screenshot for an application that will be submitted to the App Store? I've heard of other apps being rejected for taking screenshots, so I wanted to make sure this was proper.

Comment: Just taking a screenshot doesn't make them reject the app. It is the frame within which you place it.  
There is a brilliant article [here][1].


  [1]: https://iostipsntricks.wordpress.com/2011/05/12/how-not-to-get-your-ios-app-rejected-by-itunes-appstore/

Comment: I used this code to take a screenshot in the past, and Apple did not reject the app.

Answer (score 0):

That code is fine for taking a screenshot.

You've heard of apps getting rejected because there is (or used to be) a function, `UIGetScreenImage`, that would return a screen shot.  However, Apple later decided to stop allowing apps to use that function, and began rejecting apps that used it.

[Announcement allowing use of `UIGetScreenImage`](https://devforums.apple.com/thread/34908)

[Announcement prohibiting use of `UIGetScreenImage`](https://devforums.apple.com/message/266836#266836)